# Inconsistent audio over HDMI on Ubuntu 18.04 (possible codec issue?)

Tags: sound, video, hdmi

I seem to have a very strange problem- I have a Dell Latitude E6320 Laptop. This machine seems to be supported very well by Ubuntu. The problem that I am running into occurs with ***specific*** MP4 video files. All of my video files play fine through the laptop's speakers (using VLC), however, a handful of these files do not produce audio (only video) when using HDMI. I don't think that this is a configuration problem because I have several video files that ***do*** play fine through HDMI. All other audio plays fine through HDMI as well. So I think that this may be a codec problem but I can detect no differences between the particular files. I have installed the restricted extras and have even attempted to convert one of these problematic MP4 files to AVI via Handbrake- but still no audio over HDMI. Again ***all*** the video files play audio and video just fine when using the laptop's internal speakers. For the life of me, I can't understand why some MP4 files have no audio when switching the playback device to HDMI. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**EXACTLY** Same here, the case would be worse if I use my usb-c hub to connect HDMI cable (ThinkPad E580 - Ubuntu 18.04)

It seems the problem is not the Files, But randomly the player changes the output profile!

You can Install `pavucontrol`  and in Playback Tab make sure that the player uses appropriate output profile (in your case HDMI output).

Comment: Or you can get rid of Pulseaudio and install ALSA: http://linuxg.net/how-to-properly-replace-pulseaudio-with-alsa-on-crunchbag-linux-and-debian-squeeze/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar bug in 20.04. In my case videos and mp3s with audio sample rates of 48000 Hz played fine but any other sample rates (e.g. 44100 Hz) were not audible over HDMI.

To confirm this is the case, run `speaker-test -r 48000` which should play static noise through your speakers at 48000 Hz (Ctrl-C to exit).

Then try `speaker-test -r 44100` which will play the noise at 44100 Hz.

If you hear the first noise and not the second, it is the same bug.

The fix is to edit the PulseAudio daemon config file `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

Find the line:

```
; default-sample-rate = 44100
```

Change it to:

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

(remove the semi-colon at the beginning of the line and change the number to 48000)

Save the file and then restart the PulseAudio with: `pulseaudio -k`